# HashMap which only stores last N elements

Tags: java, hashmap

I´m looking for a Java HashMap implementation, which only stores the last N inserted elements and drops the oldest elements, when it would exceed the limit N by adding more elements. Is there any implementation for that?
Thanks!

Comment: This sounds more like a `Stack` that drops old entries, rather than a `Map`

Comment: @Rogue: I really don't know what makes you think that. The difference between a Stack that drops old entries and a Map that drops old entries is in how you retrieve entries from it; and the only thing that the OP has told us about his/her desired retrieval strategy is that (s)he wants a HashMap. (Or, are you thinking that using a Stack rather than a Map would help in removing old entries? It's true that it's probably easier to implement such a Stack than such a Map, but if that's not what's needed, then who cares?)

Answer (score 1):

You could extend a `LinkedHashMap` and check the size under conditions you wish for it to drop and do so. Plus, you would stay within the Java Collections Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The [LRUMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LRUMap.html) should do the trick.

Comment: Note that, although that is probably what the OP *needs*, it is not what the OP actually *describes*. I think a good answer would explain the difference.